# How to call Java method from C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I am using JNI to call my C++ function from Java. One of the C++ function's arguments is `jobject thiz` (as far as I know, all JNI native functions have this argument). The function takes quite long to complete and I want to report progress back to the `jobject thiz` Java object, so that I can show the progress to the user. How can I call jobject's methods from C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the JNI functions `GetMethodID` and `Call<type>Method*`.

The details of the various variants and how to call them are documented the [JNI specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16660).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate C++ and java with a lot less hassle, you should look into Jace http://sourceforge.net/projects/jace/